# How to join two tables multiple fields using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables with multiple columns.

### users

id  |  user_id  | **account_id**

### balance

id | **receiver_account** | **sender_account** | amount

Users table account_id will be in balance table receiver_account field or 
sender_account field. So I want to join users account_id with 
recevier_account field or sender_account field of balance table.

If I do it this way is it correct,

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN balance ON balance.receiver_account = users.account_id
        OR
        balance.sender_account = users.account_id
```

Comment: Don't you have to use a specific JOIN like INNER JOIN? Something like this `SELECT *
FROM users
INNER JOIN balance ON balance.receiver_account = users.account_id
        OR
        balance.sender_account = users.account_id`

Comment: you query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No, do this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM balance b LEFT JOIN users receiver ON b.receiver_account = receiver.account_id
LEFT JOIN users sender ON b.sender_account = sender.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select s.id, s.user_id, s.account_id, b.id, b.receiver_account , b.sender_account , b.amount 
from users s 
inner join balance b on s.account_id = b.account_id
or
b.sender_account = s.account_id
```